# A faster SQL Query to get this done

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have a SP and UDF that brings me Totals. But I know there is a `COUNT CASE WHEN` query possible to get totals in a single go. Can anyone help me in this regard? My current query is just a redundant pause.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMailBasketsForLocums] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET FMTONLY OFF;
    SET DATEFORMAT DMY; 

SELECT DISTINCT Locum.OID,
                                    Locum.FirstName + ' ' + Locum.LastName AS Name,
                                    dbo.GetMailBasketTotalsForLocums(MailBasket.LocumId, 1) AS BookingsConfirmed,
                                    dbo.GetMailBasketTotalsForLocums(MailBasket.LocumId, 3) AS BookingsCancelled,
                                    dbo.GetMailBasketTotalsForLocums(MailBasket.LocumId, 5) AS BookingsSwitched,
                                    (dbo.GetMailBasketTotalsForLocums(MailBasket.LocumId, 1) + 
                                     dbo.GetMailBasketTotalsForLocums(MailBasket.LocumId, 3) + 
                                     dbo.GetMailBasketTotalsForLocums(MailBasket.LocumId, 5)) AS Total
    FROM   MailBasket INNER JOIN
                 Locum
                 ON Locum.OID = MailBasket.LocumID
    WHERE  MailBasket.IsSent = 0
                 AND MailBasket.MailTypeID IN (1, 3, 5);
END
```

And

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMailBasketTotalsForLocums] 
(
    @LocumID BIGINT, 
    @MailTypeID INT
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @Result int

    SELECT @Result = COUNT(MailBasket.OID)
    FROM   MailBasket
    WHERE  MailBasket.MailTypeID = @MailTypeID
                 AND MailBasket.LocumID = @LocumID
                 AND MailBasket.IsSent = 0;

    RETURN @Result

END
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT Locum.OID,
     Locum.FirstName + ' ' + Locum.LastName AS Name,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN MailBasket.MailTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS BookingsConfirmed,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN MailBasket.MailTypeID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS BookingsCancelled,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN MailBasket.MailTypeID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS BookingsSwitched,
     COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM
    MailBasket INNER JOIN
             Locum
             ON Locum.OID = MailBasket.LocumID
WHERE  MailBasket.IsSent = 0
             AND MailBasket.MailTypeID IN (1, 3, 5);
```

COUNT ignores NULLs to the conditional count works

You can also use SUM

```
SUM(CASE WHEN MailBasket.MailTypeID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Locum.OID, Locum.FirstName + ' ' + Locum.LastName AS Name,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MailBasket.MailTypeID = 1 THEN MailBasket.MailTypeID END) as BookingsConfirmed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MailBasket.MailTypeID = 3 THEN MailBasket.MailTypeID END) as BookingsCancelled,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN MailBasket.MailTypeID = 5 THEN MailBasket.MailTypeID END) as BookingsSwitched,
       COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM   MailBasket INNER JOIN
             Locum
             ON Locum.OID = MailBasket.LocumID
WHERE  MailBasket.IsSent = 0
             AND MailBasket.MailTypeID IN (1, 3, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` inside a `sum` and group on the Locum records:

```
select
  Locum.OID,
  Locum.FirstName + ' ' + Locum.LastName AS Name,
  sum(case when MailBasket.MailTypeID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as BookingsConfirmed,
  sum(case when MailBasket.MailTypeID = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as BookingsCancelled,
  sum(case when MailBasket.MailTypeId = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as BookingsSwitched,
  count(*) as Total
from
  MailBasket
  inner join Locum on Locum.OID = MailBasket.LocumID
where
  MailBasket.IsSent = 0
  and MailBasket.MailTypeID IN (1, 3, 5)
group by
  Locum.OID, Locum.FirstName, Locum.LastName
```